# python 3 floor division doesn't always result in an int

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, floor-division

When using floor division in python3 (and probably also python2 with `import __future__`):

```
>>> 2//2
1
```

the output is an integer as expected. But as soon as one operand is a float, you get a float as result

```
>>> 2.0//2.0
1.0
>>> 2.0//2
1.0
>>> 2//2.0
1.0
```

I guess this is intended, but actually I don't understand, why it is supposed to be like this. What is the design concept of using a not previously determined data type as a result of an operation that always yields an integer?

The best a really extensive search gave me (from [PEP 238](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/))

> Semantics of Floor Division
>
> Floor division will be implemented in all the Python numeric
>      types, and will have the semantics of
>
> ```
>    a // b == floor(a/b)
> ```
>
> except that **the result type will be the common type into which a
>      and b are coerced before the operation.**
>
> Specifically:
>
> ```
> - If a and b are of the same type, a//b will be of that type too.
> - If the inputs are of different types, they are first coerced   
>   to a common type using the same rules used for all other arithmetic operators.
> ```
>
> In particular:
>
> ```
> - if a and b are both ints or longs, the result has the same type and value as
>   for classic division on these types (including the case of mixed input types;
>   `int//long` and `long//int` will both return a long).
> - For floating point inputs, the result is a float.
>   For example:  `3.5//2.0 == 1.0`
> - For complex numbers, // raises an exception, since floor() of a   complex number is not allowed.  
> - For user-defined classes and extension types, all semantics are up  to the implementation of the class or type.
> ```

But this still doesn't explain *WHY* the behavior is implemented like this.

Comment: "For floating point inputs, the result is a float.", so.. Maybe the "s" at input is misleading

Comment: Why not?  It's advantageous to have a well documented output type ...

Comment: @mgilson The "well documented output time" could also be `int`.

Comment: What did you think it should be? Bigint?  DBL_MAX//1 would need quite a large integer.

Comment: @delnan -- Yes, but any choice is somewhat arbitrary here (as far as I can see).  In general, asking *why* someone chose to design an API a certain way isn't really an easy to answer question (or on topic for StackOverflow IMHO)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible advantage can be the following: If the inputs of an operation are `float`s, then usually the most useful output type is a `float`, because the program is doing floating point calculations. Similarly, if the inputs of an operation are integers (`int`s or `long`s), then usually the most useful output type is an integer.

A related surprising data point:

```
>>> str(int(123e300 // 10.0))
'12300000000000000348405169443457756499452463917650245579212965288916278422109198944984236481408634018703901759913201583616648277756338685989513894763895354330869046350917957229381143786183918719192956157930593465276658607709014541611368487360619735051905095032755082564499801643679232993692080863707136'
```

It's surprising, because it's natural to expect lots of `0`s at the end. You get other digits because of the limited precision of the `float` type.

So by returning a `float`, `//` indicates that the output can be inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

This makes floor division consistent with the other arithmetic operations. The advantage is that instead of remembering that `//` is a special case, you can use your existing knowledge and coding patterns. And as with all the other operators, if you want to force the output to be an `int` you should explicitly coerce it to be such.