# What's the rationale behind 2.5 // 2.0 returning a float rather than an int in Python 3.x?

Tags: python

What's the rationale behind  `2.5 // 2.0` returning a `float` rather than an `int` in Python 3.x?
If it's an integral value, why not put it in a type `int` object?

[edit]

I am looking for a justification of the fact that this is so. What were the arguments in making it this way. Haven't been able to find them yet.

[edit2]

The relation with `floor` is more problematic than the term "floor division" suggests!

`floor(3.5 / 5.5) == 0` (int)

whereas

`3.5 // 5.5 == 0.0` (float)

Can not yet discern any logic here :(

[edit3]

From PEP238:

> In a
>       unified model, the integer 1 should be indistinguishable from the
>       floating point number 1.0 (except for its inexactness), and both
>       should behave the same in all numeric contexts.

All very nice, but a not unimportant library like Numpy complains when offering floats as indices, even if they're integral. So 'indistinguishable' is not reality yet. Spent some time hunting a bug in connection with this. I was very surprise to learn about the true nature of `//`. And it wasn't that obvious from the docs (for me).

Since I've quite some trust in the design of Python 3.x, I thought I must have missed a very obvious reason to define `//` in this way. But now I wonder...

Comment: It returns a float because both of the numbers are floats. Adding a ".0" at the end of an integer turns it into a float in Python.

Comment: @SparklePony that might be the rule, but a rule is not a reason. I think this is an interesting question.

Comment: @SparklePony: It's obvious that both of the arguments are floats. That doesn't mean the output has to be a float. We already have 1/2 returning a float; why not have 1.0//2.0 return an int?

Comment: _"If it's an integral value
..."_ But it is not an integral value. Did you mean something else?

Comment: Let me get this straight... `/` was problematic because of the ambiguity, it's result depends on the type of the numbers. So we fixed that *and* added a new operator with the same (well, similar) issue. How charming...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Well, the _type_ of the result depends on the input, but with the "new" `/` and `//` you won't be surprised by the result being rounded just because the inputs happen to be integers anymore.

Comment: @tobias_k: yes, that was clear to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209232/python-3-floor-division-is-not-always-resulting-in-an-int

Answer (score 6):

The `//` operator is covered in [PEP 238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/). First of all, note that it's not "integer division" but "floor division", i.e. it is never claimed that the result would be an integer.

From the section on *Semantics of Floor Division*:

> Floor division will be implemented in all the Python numeric types, and will have the semantics of
>
> ```
> a // b == floor(a/b)
> ```
>
> except that the result type will be the common type into which a and b are coerced before the operation.

And later:

> For floating point inputs, the result is a float.  For example:
>
> ```
> 3.5//2.0 == 1.0
> ```

The rationale behind this decision is not explicitly stated (or I could not find it). However, the way it is implemented, it is consistent with the other mathematical operations (emphasis mine):

> Specifically, if a and b are of the same type, `a//b` will be of that type too.  If the inputs are of different types, they are first coerced to a common type **using the same rules used for all other arithmetic operators**.

Also, if the results would be automatically converted to `int`, that could yield weird and surprising results for very large floating point numbers that are beyond integer precision:

```
>>> 1e30 // 2.
5e+29
>>> int(1e30 // 2.)
500000000000000009942312419328
```

Comment: Is there any reasoning in the PEP for this decision? If not, we are still just pointing to a rule, without an explanation...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath See my edit. I guess the main reason is (a) being consistent with other arithmetic operations, and (b) not messing around with large floating point numbers.

Comment: "weird and surprising results for very large floating point numbers that are beyond integer precision" - other way around. It's the floating-point numbers that are losing precision. The integer conversion just makes the precision loss obvious, by displaying more digits.

Comment: @tobias_k 'using the same rules for all other arithmetic operators'. Maybe that's it. Deserves some more attention in the docs, though (unless I missed something), especially since 'floor' behaves different from 'floor division', while the names suggest they behave similar.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge The weird thing is: With the new division, `//` behaves that way, but `/` no longer does, yielding a float even if both arguments were int... About `floor`: Note that that's technically not an arithmetic operation but a function.